# How many and what databases I have to create for a WSO2 EI two node cluster like this (each node contains ESB and MB profiles)

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-message-broker, wso2-esb

I am installing a WSO2 EI two nodes cluster and I have some doubts about the number of databases that have to be created.

I will try to explain my situation as best that I can: I am using **WSO2 EI 6.5.0**.

I have two nodes cluster. Each node contains the **ESB** and the **MB** profile. I will create the needed databases on a **Microsoft SQL Server** cluster DB.

So I have this situation:

**NODE 1: ESB AND MB**

**NODE 2: ESB AND MB**

Reading on the official documentation:

**CLUSTERING WSO2 ESB PROFILE:** https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Clustered+Deployment

**CLUSTERING WSO2 MB PROFILE:** https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Clustering+the+Message+Broker+Profile

I can found information of the DBs needed by ESB and MB profiles.
In particular **ESB** profile need the creation of these 4 databases:

- **WSO2_USER_DB:** JDBC user store and authorization manager.
- **REGISTRY_DB:** Shared database for config and governance registry mounts in the product's nodes.
- **REGISTRY_LOCAL1:** Local registry space in Node 1.
- **REGISTRY_LOCAL2:** Local registry space in Node 2.

while **MB** profile need the following 5 databases:

- **WSO2_USER_DB:** JDBC user store and authorization manager.
- **REGISTRY_DB:** Shared database for config and governance registry mounts in the product's nodes.
- **REGISTRY_LOCAL1:** Local registry space in Node 1.
- **REGISTRY_LOCAL2:** Local registry space in Node 2.
- **MB_DB:** Stores instance data that are specific to the message broker profile.

So it appears that the first 4 databases are the same between the **ESB** and **MB** profiles and that the **MB** profiles uses an addictional database named **MB_DB**.

And here my doubt: in a situation like the one that I have (2 nodes cluster that both contains **ESB** and **MB** profiles) how many databases have do I have to create?

My original idea was 5 databases because I thought that the first 4 databases are shared between **ESB** and **MB** profiles but now I have the following doubt: in theory (correct me if I am doing wrong assertion) **both ESB and MB may use same user database and registry** but checking the default **H2** setup we have that:

- **ESB** profile use one database placed in **/usr/lib/wso2/wso2ei/6.5.0/repository/database/**
- **MB** profile use one database placed in **/usr/lib/wso2/wso2ei/6.5.0/wso2/broker/repository/database/**

So in theory it should mean that it is better to do not mix databases between profile/products.

So what exactly I should do? How many and what databases I have to create?

I am now thinking that maybe I have to completly separate the **ESB** and **MB** profiles databases using prefix, something like this:

**ESB** profile databases: I have to create these 4 databases:

- **ESB_WSO2_USER_DB**
- **ESB_REGISTRY_DB**
- **ESB_REGISTRY_LOCAL1**
- **ESB_REGISTRY_LOCAL2**

**MB** profiles databases: I have to create these 5 databases;

- **MB_WSO2_USER_DB**
- **MB_REGISTRY_DB**
- **MB_REGISTRY_LOCAL1**
- **MB_REGISTRY_LOCAL2**
- **WSO2_MB** (specific for **MB** profile so I am not using a reduntant suffix)

Could this be a good solution? But in this way I will have completlely separate dbs and not shared information for users and registry.

What is the best practice in a case like a two nodes cluster like mine?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, it is fine to keep separate databases. And what usually does is creating databases with a prefix as you mentioned.

However, let's say if its only one set of users that will be accessing both ESB and MB, then you can go ahead and point a single userdb from the both products (means all the four instances running in 2 nodes).

Regarding the registry database, let say if you have a configuration file that needs to be access from both ESB and MB, then you have to share a single registry_db (and also have to follow the proper registry mounting / see the docs for that).
If there is no such case, it is best to keep separate databases.

Bottom line: As long as there is nothing to be shared between ESB and MB internally, it is best to maintain a separate set of databases. You only need to follow clustering and share databases only between the instances of the same product.

Cheers!